# Event Receiver Rename file

Tags: event-receivers, event-handlers

I am trying to rename file( removing few unwanted characters adding few etc). I am able to do it via **itemadded** event I have tried `SPFile.MoveTo( works fine)` and simple changing `property["Name"]`  it works as well.

My issue is that none of these ways are making versions, `MoveTo` just removes existing file and creates/moves new(tried overwrite option but didn't helped) where changing property name doesn't work if filename is already in use.

I have tried **itemadding** event but that doesn't work for me either.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Before I try a full reply, you claim to have already tried using **itemAdding** instead. What have you actually tried? I think it could work, but you would need to use the `AfterProperties` collection instead of accessing the ListItem instance. Have you tried something like `properties.AfterProperties["Title"] =  newFileTitle`?

Comment: No, i am using name property, internalname of "name" `properties.AfterProperties["internalname oF Name"] = new filename `

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.Update()` or `.SystemUpdate(true)` in your event receiver code as both should increment the version.  [refer this blog](https://amtopmblog.azurewebsites.net/2011/09/06/update-vs-systemupdate-vs-updateoverwriteversion/)

Comment: Yeah they both increase the version, probably you are talking about the second approach i have mentioned. If i try to rename a file and the new name is already in use it doesn't work so no versions :(.`update` or `systemupdate`doesn't come in the picture.